# When to use multiple comparison adjustment - guide for layman

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I'm frequently asked when multiple comparison adjustment should be used. Then I start talking about false discovery rate, type-I errors and so on, to conclude that I was not fully understood. So I came with a following example (maybe "show don't tell" rule applies to data analysis too ;) ):

*Imagine, you compare three parameters, P1, P2 and P3 in two groups (control and treatment, say), and get p=0,03 for each parameter.
Now, if you apply Bonferroni correction, you'll reduce number of significant results from 3 to 0 (or to 1 or 2 with other corrections).
But you really, really love your tripple significance, so you write three articles, one for each parameter, and send them to three distinct journals. Now, no one asks you for multiple comparisons adjustment! The moral is: if you can sensibly (forget about ethics for a while) split your results into distinct papers/threads, you probably do not need adjustments.*

My question is: what do you think? Does above "rule of thumb for layman" make any sense?

To be clear: I know that right answer to the question from title is much more complicated.

Comment: I don't know... everyone will have their own interpretation of what "sensibly split" means.

Comment: The same applies to deciding if 5%probability of  type-I error in each comparison is much/less desirable than 5% probability of type-I error in at least one comparison. Everyone will have their own opinion. But I believe, it's easier for a layman to give an answer to "sensible split" question than to "type-I error" question.